# Tree operations (find) using indices (inode numbers) to address files/directories

Tags: filesystems, tree

(removed OS mention, since I need 'general Unix/Linux' solution)

Task: perform operation over files/directories, in "find way", but assuming that file/directory pathnames can change in process.

Typical problem with 'find' is when something is renamed, find attempts to stat the entity and reports it can't find it. If it would operate with indices, such a problem wouldn't exist (at a cost of reverse lookup, inode -> pathname and perhaps additional name matching).

At the moment, I get list of subject files/directories, obtain their indices and use something like 'find path -inum index' to get current name to perform operation over file. The script looks rather clumsy because of that.

Is there more elegant way, perhaps there's a clone of 'find' able to operate with indices as well, rather than with cached pathnames?

Comment: Well, the problem with this approach is that you need to get inode numbers first. If there's large amount of files, that can mean a lot of inode numbers.  I'd recommend you approach the issue in different way - `find` the files, and pass their full path to `xargs` for processing with a command.

Comment: I don't think you're going to come up with a good solution with scripts.  Even the hack you are using can fail if the file gets renamed at exactly that point.  If you wrote your own program in C, it can open the files and once you have that handle to the file it will persist even if the file gets renamed in the file system (or even if it gets `rm`ed, you can still read it, it's just not in the directory anymore, that's why the command has that name).

Answer (score 0):

From context, I infer that when you write “indices”, you actually mean [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). In case you did mean indices, note that a directory does *not* consist of a list of files in a well-defined order where you can say “I want the file at index 3”. Directories are indexed by names: you say “I want the file called `foo`”. The order of files in a directory can change at any time.

Assuming you do mean inodes, there is no way to access a file by its inode. This is by design: file paths are how permissions are enforced. Accessing a file by its inode would bypass all permission checks on the directory that contains it. It would also only be possible on filesystem that have a concept of inode by design, rather than pulling inode numbers out of thin air just because the API requires it. So if you only know the inode of a file, searching for it until you find a name is the only way to operate on that file.

Even if there was a way to find a file by inode, it wouldn't solve your problem, it would just move it around a little. It would make it transparent when a file is renamed after `find` has found it and before it does something with it. However, if the file has been deleted and another file has been created with the same inode, `find` would access the wrong file.

There is no way with a file API to take an atomic snapshot of a directory tree. There are several solutions to your problem; which one(s) can work for you depends on your usage scenario.

- Ensure that your task copes with modifications of the tree that it's operating on.
- Ensure that all the applications that modify the directory tree are paused while your task is running.
- Use a lower-level API to take a snapshot and operate on the (read-only) snapshot. Some filesystems such as zfs and btrfs can do it, as can volume types such as LVM.

Comment: Yes, it's about inodes.     
  
Unfortunately, I cannot request using certain type of filesystem, or rely on LVM volume type. Looks like there's single reliable solution - handling all logic of names/paths change in the script program performing files procesing.